# woocommerce составные заголовки. Заголовок из несколько полей

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Можно ли в Woo сделать как составные заголовки ?

У меня много товаров и они все называются сначала так: "**Полнорационный сухой корм для взрослых котов......**"  вместо точек идут разные вкусовые добавки "**с уткой**" и еще бывает в заголовке типа что это дает животному "**блеск шерсти**".

В админку планируеться так заполнять
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом заголовки хоть и состоят из несколько полей но везде должно быть как 1 целый выводиться.

Конечная цель в том чтоб в списке можно было красиво заголовки выводить.

Comment: вариативный товар

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/

Comment: не то, я вариации знаю. Мне как бы в самом тайтле надо такое намутить

Comment: а зачем разделение если это простой товар ? Почему сразу нужный заголовок не ставить в название ?

Comment: @Valerii Vasiliev

Чтоб в списках можно было красиво выводить заголовок. Конкретные части заголовков выделять. Но при этом чтоб в админки было легко редактировать.

Comment: написал реализацию через фильтрацию заголовков в ответе

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте фильтры на заголовки

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );

remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_title',5);

add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 10 );

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title',5);

function custom_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title() {
    
    $title = get_the_title();
    
    $title1 = get_field('title1', get_the_ID());
    
    $title2 = get_field('title2', get_the_ID());
    
    echo $title.' '.$title1.' '.$title2;
}
```

где фрагмент предполагает использование acf

```
$title1 = get_field('title1', get_the_ID());
    
$title2 = get_field('title2', get_the_ID());
```

Answer (score 1):

На сколько понимаю это кастомные поля: "С чем корм" и "Что дает нам это", следовательно в шаблоне страницы где получаете H1 добавьте вывод этих полей, пример:

```html
<h1><?=the_title()?> <? the_field('s-chem-korm') ?> <? the_field('chto-daet-eto-nam') ?></h1>
или
<h1><? echo get_the_title() . " " . get_the_field(s-chem-korm') . " " . get_the_field('chto-daet-eto-nam'); ?></h1>
```

Или с проверкой на заполнение:

```
<?
    if (isset(get_the_field('s-chem-korm')) && !empty(get_the_field('s-chem-korm'))) {
        $cf1 = get_the_field('s-chem-korm');
    }

    if (isset(get_the_field('chto-daet-eto-nam')) && !empty(get_the_field('chto-daet-eto-nam'))) {
        $cf2 = get_the_field('chto-daet-eto-nam');
    }
?>
```

Выводим:

```html
<h1><? echo get_the_title() . " " . $cf1 . " " . $cf2; ?></h1>
```